# Telegram bots API responds 403 Forbidden - when send direct message to bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

$apiToken = "5232750517:AAF7gbXCwZdfhSQeZZb53-2NhTm2xxNuT3U";

```
          $data = [
              'chat_id' => '5232750517',
              'text' => 'Hello World'
          ];
          $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" .
                                         http_build_query($data) );
```

The error message

> Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Then I am followed this solution - [Telegram bots API responds 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061906/telegram-bots-api-responds-403-forbidden)

My bot username is @test247_bot and change the code to:

```
$apiToken = "5232750517:AAF7gbXCwZdfhSQeZZb53-2NhTm2xxNuT3U";

  $data = [
      'chat_id' => '5232750517',
      'text' => 'Hello World'
  ];
  $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/@test247_bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" .
                                 http_build_query($data) );
```

But also did not work, the error message

> Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct way to build your URL.

Remove your bot's username. It is simply "bot" followed by api token instead.

Try:

```
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot5232750517:AAF7gbXCwZdfhSQeZZb53-2NhTm2xxNuT3U/sendMessage?" .http_build_query($data) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But doesn't work, error 403

Comment: `https://api.telegram.org/bot5232750517:AAF7gbXCwZdfhSQeZZb53-2NhTm2xxNuT3U/sendMessage?chat_id=5232750517&text=Hello world"`

The above URL always gives error 403

This issue because send direct message to 'bot' which chat id and first part of token is the same

How to solve this?

Comment: Telegram will respond with 403 when trying to send a message to a user who has blocked your bot. `Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user`. Make sure that's not the case. Also note a user has to initiate a conversation with your bot first before you are allowed to send any messages.

Comment: My bot is not blocked by anyone because the users of this bot only me on 2 phone numbers.

 If I change the chat id, e.g. `https://api.telegram.org/bot5232750517:AAF7gbXCwZdfhSQeZZb53-2NhTm2xxNuT3U/sendMessage?chat_id=12346781&text=Hello world"` it works fine. But when chat id is the same with first part of the token (which chat id of the bot) then it gets 403 error

Comment: I fail to understand what you are trying to achieve here. You are essentially telling the bot to send a message to itself.  Which is not possible. The error message you receive is pretty clear too: `Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots`

Comment: To get other user chat id, the user have to send message to bot first, then the chat id of the users will appear on https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates. That what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Users can send message to bot from Telegram on their phone. How to be able send message to bot from api.telegram.org? That what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Bot API is not capable of sending messages on behalf of a user.  This is not a part of Bot Api. You would need to use "Telegram API" and/or "TDLib" to do such things. Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: You are right, I should use  "Telegram API" and/or "TDLib". Thanks a lot for the guidance,